# Web API2 PUT not updating many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, put

I got some troubles with my web api when using the `PUT` method. It updates the `FooBar` object but it doesn't update the changes in the `Bars` collection. I'm mainly trying to adding and/or removing `Bar` objects from the collection.

These are my two classes

```
public class FooBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
}
```

I've got the `[JsonIgnore]` to avoid JSON circular references.

This is the `PUT`method:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutBundle(FooBar fooBar)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    foreach (Bar b in fooBar.Bars)
    {
        db.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    db.Entry(fooBar).State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Looking at some other questions it seems like adding `EntityState.Modified` to the `Bar` objects would solve the problem but it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: If you set a break point at `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`, do you see ***Bars***  objects inside ***fooBar*** object. In other words, do you see all posted data?

Comment: Yes, `Bars` is populated with the correct number of objects and with correct values as I asssume `Bars.FooBars` should be `null` because of the `[JsonIgnore]` decoration. Noticed now I did the `[JsonIgnore]` decoration on the wrong class in this question but I have updated it.